# Enable Vorto text in Archetype - Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, archetypes

I have Archetype in umbraco 7.4.3
When I set vorto text box in the archetype I get:

[image]

Its look like the vorto box is disabled.
whenever I set the vorto (translated) text box in simple document type it work's perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find answer that works perfect for me.

In the "vorto.js" file their is a function named "getDataTypeById".

In this function their is a call to another function named "getDataTypeByAlias".

[image]

After the inner function call the parameter "dataType2" is returned as "null" so we need to set "if" statement that checks if "dataType2" is "null" and if the code returns "true" we will assign:

```
dataType2 = dataType;
```

Their only one problem left.. when the data type is "rich text editor" it's trow exception so i added to the condition another check and now its look like this:

```
if (dataType2 && dataType.propertyEditorAlias != "Umbraco.TinyMCEv3") {
                dataType2 = dataType;
            }
```

I hope its helps others...

Answer (score 2):

Vorto nested in an Archetype doesn't work ootb they both have to be modified in order to work this way. An alternative is to wrap Vorto around your Archetype. However if this isn't suitable for you setup see the following issue on the Archetype github, which has a pull request which should show you want needs to be changed. https://github.com/imulus/Archetype/issues/235